# Find exactly where the memory leak is in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I have a class:

```
class MyObject {
    var id = 0

    init() {
        print(“MyObject created”)
    }

    deinit {
        print(“MyObject released”)
    }

    static func new() -> MyObject {
        let obj = MyObject()
        obj.id = RandomNumber() // only calculation
        return obj
    }
}
```

My code in View controller:

```
var myObj: MyObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      self.myObj = MyObject()
  }

  deinit {
    print(”ViewController released")
  }
```

Both MyObject and ViewController are released based on my log. But I still got a memory leak when I check with Memory Debug Graph tool of Xcode.

[image]

You can see the object is not owned by anybody but I see the object is released. Can anybody advise on what could be the reason cause the memory leak? Thanks.

Comment: how do you know its the `MyObject`object?

Comment: Honestly, I would blame Instruments / Xcode - I frequently get strange memory leakages reported, which obviously do not exist. You could try and make `MyObject` a very large one (allocate a large array or something) and then check the overall memory footprint of your app (e.g. check if there is a large peak that then shrinks once the Viewcontroller and `MyObject` are freed).

Comment: @MilanNosáľ It shows MyObject below the blue Cubicle.